# Docker network not found after reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After rebooting my PC `docker-compose up` throws the following error for stopped containers:

```
docker network <id> not found
```

Only solution I found so far is to remove all containers by `docker-compose down` and re-create the containers by `docker-compose up`.

I am using Docker for Windows, and use a default network configuration (i.e. no network specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file).

Anyone else having this problem?
How to solve this?

Comment: Docker and docker-compose versions? Have you checked this? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
networks:
  test:
    external:
      name: nat
```

to `docker-compose.yml` and using the `test` network for each service solves it.